# Find Nonzero values in an arbitrary matrix

Tags: matlab

I need a code that receives an arbitrary matrix and find the nonzero values 
the harder approach is needed not simple commands like nnz ! 
i tried this

```
  m = input( ' Enter row elements of a matrix ' ) ; 
n = input( ' Enter column elements of a matrix ' ) ; 
for i = 1 : m 
    for j = 1 : n 
        m = find( m == 0 ) ;
        n = find ( n == 0 ) ;
    end
end
```

but then it resulted in an error : Unexpected matlab expression

Comment: Just do this - `m(m~=0)` and `n(n~=0)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how is your matrix populated? Do you wish to create a new matrix? zeros? ones?

You can simply use the `find` function to look for non-zero element. This will return a vector with the location of non-zero elements.